# Sitecore Identity callback path issue

Tags: identity-server, redirect

I have set up 2 identity provider plugins in sitecore identity, one is being used for `/sitecore` login the other is used for one of our portals to authenticate against. Both use Okta as the IdP, however they are using 2 different instances (one is for internal employees, the other is for application users).

The issue I am having is that when the application users hit Okta and then redirect back to the identity server `/signin-idsrv` endpoint the identity server falls back to using the employee version of the Okta plugin. Is there something I am missing configuration wise that can solve this issue? I believe the issue is that the identity server does not know which Okta instance is redirecting back to it and so it handles it using the first identity plugin it finds in the config.

I think this might be the issue as both plugins use the same paths currently.

```
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-idsrv");
options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout/callback");
```

`loginPage="$(loginPath)admin-portal/SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-OktaGroupPortal"`

```
<configuration>
    <sitecore>
        <federatedAuthentication>
            <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
                <mapEntry name="admin portal" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                    <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-OktaGroupPortal']" />
                    </identityProviders>
                    <sites hint="list">
                        <site>admin-portal</site>
                    </sites>
                    <externalUserBuilder type="MLCGP.Security.Feature.Pipelines.CustomExternalUserBuilder, MLCGP.Security.Feature" resolve="true">
                        <IsPersistentUser>true</IsPersistentUser>
                    </externalUserBuilder>
                </mapEntry>
            </identityProvidersPerSites>
            <identityProviders>
                <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-OktaGroupPortal" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                    <caption>Log in with Okta</caption>
                    <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png</icon>
                    <domain>portal</domain>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </identityProvider>
            </identityProviders>
            <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <maps hint="list">
                    <map name="name to FullName" resolve="true"
                      type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                        <data hint="raw:AddData">
                            <source name="name"/>
                            <target name="FullName" />
                        </data>
                    </map>
                </maps>
            </propertyInitializer>
        </federatedAuthentication>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have setup two separate identity providers in config, then you should just be able to use the Ids of those providers as part of the login paths.

See example below, which uses ADFS and Azure as two separate providers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProviders>
        <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-AzureAd" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>Log in with Sitecore Identity: Azure AD</caption>
          <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png</icon>
        </identityProvider>
        <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-WsFederation" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>Log in with Sitecore Identity: ADFS</caption>
          <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png</icon>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>
    </federatedAuthentication>
    <sites>
      <site name="your-site-name" loginPage="$(loginPath)your-site-name/SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-WsFederation" />
      <site name="shell" loginPage="$(loginPath)shell/SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-AzureAd" />
    </sites>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then when you go to either site to login, then it should provide a different redirect URL.

How does your config compare to the example above?

Comment: Adding that has solved it for me, my issue was that I had the wrong id (I did not prefix with `SitecoreIdentityServer`)

Comment: Actually this did not work once I changed the callback path specified in the Identity Provider plugin

Comment: So it logs them into sitecore shell rather than the front end application? Can you share the relevant sitecore config in question?

Comment: I have added the relevant config, did you also want the identity server config as well?

Comment: Looking at your config, it seems you have only configured one <identityprovider> with id=SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-OktaGroupPortal. If you have configured two in identity server, then you should have two corresponding ones in your config. You can then use the id from each in the login path. Note, in my example there are two providers and each are used as values for loginPage param. for respective sites.

Comment: the default Identity server entry is present from the `\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config` as for the other Okta one, I have not needed to define it for the button to appear in the `/sitecore/login` url...

Comment: Can you share the config that defines your loginPage param for each site please? Your main issue defined in the question is that you have two OKTA plugins and you cant hook each to different sites in Sitecore. Yet from what I have seen Sitecore has no knowledge of two OKTA providers, so how do you expect it to differentiate between them? The  buttons showing in sitecore identity server means nothing, unless Sitecore (instance) chooses which to use and link to a site.

Comment: I have added the login page to the question body above. I have managed to get this working at the moment by defining 2 subproviders, however I am now getting issues when creating the user account where the domain setting is not coming through correctly, I have it set to portal but it comes through as sitecore every time

Comment: Did you create new domain and also add it to the site config. You might find info here useful https://deanobrien.uk/sitecore-identity-server-mapping-custom-fields-and-roles-from-azure-ad/

Comment: Adding domain helped, I also needed to manually set the domain for the user using the DefaultExternalUserBuilder, it all appears to work as intended now